# How to prevent a SPAN Tag inside a button from linebreaking (jQuery UI button)

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I want to generate several [split buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton) using jQuery UI. 
The buttons should fill their container up to 100% (the container has a fixed width). If the text of the button is too long I want it to be cut off.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBjst/) demonstrates the problem. Is there any easy solution the button is displayed in one line and the long text is cut off?

The problem seems to be that the *span* element inside the *button* tag doesn't do any line breaking even if its width is set by hand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#buttons {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.ui-button-text {
    max-width:60px; /* Adjust this to make wider/narrower */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/gwSuB/

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

`<div style="width:100px;overflow-x: hidden">`

`<div id="buttons">`

`<button id="btn1" style="white-space: nowrap">very very very very long text</button>`

`<button id="btn2">delete</button>`

`</div>`
`</div>`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your answer. Tags are automatically removed from your answer here. If you wrote some please format them as 'code'

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this so I was trying to format it :)   Please take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

you have the button inside a 100px wide div. is this necessary? See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBjst/12/

Comment: Oh, after looking at your jsfiddle I see what you are talking about. I guess I just didn't understand the question. 1up for you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncguN/

FYI, the most important CSS styles in the solution are:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I'm using exactly the same version too.. "16.0.912.77 m" - I wonder what could be wrong.

Comment: ahh.. ok you mean the second button falls to the next line.. yes, i haven't fixed that..